# To many idle connects to DB with Spring Boot JDBC

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I use **Spring Boot JDBC** to pool data from **Oracle RDBMS** - there is one select which pools data about 7 mil rows.

Here is the configuration which I use :

```
      "jdbc.query": "SQL",
      "spring.datasource.driver-class-name": "com.exasol.jdbc.EXADriver",
      "spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size": 1,
```

Problem is, I have a lot of idle connections which come fast every minute.

I tried with set maximum-pool-size =1 but it doesn't work.

Can you give me some advice, how to avoid idle session with DB?

Could EXADriver alse be a problem?

Comment: By default the app opens 10 connections for reuse with the database. They appear idle on the db side if there isn't much data. Why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: Good point :), but th customer complains because of the distribution of resources within the database and the reason is (based on his explanation) a lot of idle connections.

Comment: Any connection will appear idle in a view like V$SESSION unless it happens to be doing something at the *exact* moment you check on it. Since most actions take less than a second to complete, most sessions will generally appear idle at any given time. That doesn't mean that they aren't actually doing anything, or that they aren't needed by the app. There isn't anything to worry about in terms of resources unless you are generating so many dedicated server processes that it is using up all of your memory on the server. How many sessions are we talking about, and which resources?

Comment: There are about 400 idle connections per day and sessions last between 5 - 30 minutes. Otherwise, according to requirement,  I need just one session weekly to simply pull data from DB.  Process is started through cron job.  I forgot to mention 
jdbc.streaming-mode-enabled": true,